# Preg_replace multiple searches in one string

Tags: php, regex, preg-replace

I'm trying to create a function for users to user a shortcode in there text for some basic information like published date, changed date, author etc.

In the string they will place things like

```
{datePublished}%Y-%d{/datePublished}

{dateChanged}%Y-%d{/dateChanged}

{author} writen by {/author}
```

I thought using a regex replace was the way to go, so I made this pattern:

```
$regex = "#(.*)([{]datePublished[}])(.*)([{]/datePublished[}])(.*)#e";
```

This works, but there is one problem. How can I loop the string containing all those different shortcodes through the different patterns, keeping the information intact.

This is my test string: `{datePublished}%A %d %h. %Y %H.%M uur{/datePublished} {dateChanged} | laatst gewijzigd: %A %d %h. %H.%M uur{/dateChanged} {author} | auteur: {/author}`

Any suggestions?

Regards,
Tim

Comment: please be more accurate: does the users input between the tags (`%Y-%d`) have impact on the final formating, or does the content between `{datePublished}` and `{/datePublished}` doesn't have any impact?

Comment: Not clear to me... What is exactly the expected output from your test string above ?